# How do I setup If else statement in linq

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I want to evaluate the result of a query and switch based on the result.  If 'chk' query comes back as "0" from the t.c_pointsTotal column use query1.  I think I am running into dataType issues(evaluating as string because that's all I know how to do)???  In the db c_pointsTotal is a float.  How do I accomplish this ?  As it is the code below does not evaluate correctly.

p.s. If some one is feeling up to it can you please tell me when or why to use Linq as apposed to SQL (with DataReader) to get the same effect.

```
String zero = "0";
var chk = (from t in db.t_BannerUsers
           where t.c_call_id.ToString().ToLower().Equals(c_call_id.ToLower())     
           &&  t.c_user_id.ToString().ToLower().Equals(c_user_id.ToLower())
           select ((t.c_pointsTotal))).ToString();

if (String.Equals(chk, zero))
{
    return(query1.....)
}
else
{
    return (query2....)
}
```

Comment: What is the type of `c_call_id`?

Comment: What's not working about the code you've got? Have you tried attaching a debugger and evaluating chk?

Comment: Currently, the page loads and no matter what the value of 'chk' it always goes to query1. When I try to debug 'chk' does not show me the result of the query just the query it's self ???

Comment: c_call_id is dataType varchar ???

Answer (score 1):

First, you must be sure the query returns only one result.

Regarding data types, you can change this:

```
String zero = "0";
```

to this:

```
decimal zero=0;
```

Answer (score 0):

`chk` is a sequence of items.  `zero` is a single string.  If `chk` will only return 1 item you can use the LINQ `First` method to get that item, or `FirstOrDefault` if it could be empty.  If it could return several, you'll need to decide how you want it to behave.  Should it just look at the first, check all of them, etc.

Edit: actually you call `ToString` on the query, so you'll just get `"IEnumerable<string>" in the query; you should remove that ToString`.

Comment: what is this 'First' method that you speak of...and How or where do I use the 'First' method ?

Comment: MSDN is your friend ... First - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb291976.aspx ... FirstOrDefault - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340482.aspx

Comment: @AhavLives What was the value of `chk` after making my changes?  What do you expect it to be?

Comment: Unable to cast object of type 'System.Double' to type 'System.String'.   After adding the First() method and droping the toString()---------        var chk = (from t in db.t_Noni_BannerUsers
                       where t.c_call_id.ToString().ToLower().Equals(c_call_id.ToLower()) && t.c_user_id.ToString().ToLower().Equals(c_user_id.ToLower())
                       select t.c_pointsTotal).First();

Comment: @AhavLives Well, that's not no difference.  Since the type is now returning the value that you want, and not an `IEnumerable`, you can call `ToString` on it and get the string value of the double, rather than the string value of the query, and compare it to a string.  Alternatively, you could declare 'zero' as a double, and not a string.